# Como puedo cargar un archivo pdf en c #, a través de input file y enviarlo por correo electrónico?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Alguién sabe como puedo cargar un archivo desde un input fila, y enviarlo por correo electrónico, he buscado pero solo aparecen ejemplos cargando un solo archivo. Yo solicito que se cargue cada vez que un usuario lo necesite.

---

Input de tipo file, estoy realizando una aplicación web de asp .net mvc utilizando entity framework, las vistas son con etiquetas con código razor. La idea es que el usuario cargue un archivo a través de un input y luego que se envíe a una casilla de correo electrónico. El lenguaje es c#, la carga puede ser binaria.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: que es una "input fila" ? que tipo de proyecto estas realizando? explicate mas completo

Comment: Cuando atacas un problema de programación es practico dividirlo por partes e ir solucionando cada parte (como un modelo por capas). Tienes una parte avanzada, sabes:1) en que lenguaje lo quieres hacer: C# 2) Los pasos a)Cargar un archivo PDF 3)Enviarlo por correo electronico. Te sugeriria que plantearas en preguntas aparte cada uno de los pasos, ampliando en cada una los requisitos. Ej: En la carga debes ampliar que tipo de carga te interesa: ¿Carga binaria? ¿Carga con metadatos? ¿Carga para manipulacion del PDF?

Comment: Las respuestas obtenidas no son de mucha ayuda, ya he encontrado una posible solución en cuanto a la carga del archivo!!